# Need help regarding few config.xml tags

Tags: magento-1.6

Now I am create Magento new reCaptcha module. Some where I have read to use this below code in `config.xml`.

```
<adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <namespace_module>
                                            <title>Recaptcha</title>
                                        </namespace_module>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
```

Is anyone who can explain me the meaning of these tags please.
Thanks

Comment: This is a good place to start: http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited

Comment: @Vicky could you add your comment as answer, including a snippet of content from the link which is relevant so johnwright121 can accept it as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a hierarchical tree structure that defines all sorts of permissions for backend functionality.

Magento doesn’t automatically derive ACL permissions for added menu items. Whenever you add a new menu item, you also need to add nodes to your configuration defining an access control permission.

The following configuration will add ACL permissions to a menu item located under System > Configuration > Recaptcha

```
<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <namespace_module>
                                        <title>Recaptcha</title>
                                    </namespace_module>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
```

With this in place, you can manage the permissions for this menu item in the System > Permissions > Roles section.

`namespace_module` is a node you define specifically for your module and should match the node you defined for your menu item.

Source and more information: 
http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited